# Can't add Maven Dependency to Source tab of Remote Debugging Configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I want to add Maven Dependency to Java Build Path for a project. But it just display the screen to add, I hit finish button, but nothing is added to build path.

Anyone can give me a hint?

[image]

Edit question:

According guidance from below guys. I find that when project have a pom.xml, Maven Dependency is automatically added to Java Build Path. But Maven Dependency isn't added automatically to Remote Debug configurations, so eclipse can't see source code of jars in repository when remote debugging (although they're all downloaded when I build projects). And I can't force to add it as well. The symptom's manifest is similar to the picture above.

Please advice more.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Is your project a *maven* project and do does it have a `pom.xml` with dependency declarations? (sorry for asking trivial questions)

Comment: I use m2eclipse plugin and have pom.xml with dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you have install m2e plugin for your eclipse and create a maven project from eclipse then you dont need to manually add maven dependencies. Eclipse will automatically download required dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Eclipse maven project has **Maven Dependencies** in Java Build Path. If it is missed then you can repair Eclipse project from command line

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and then refresh Eclipse project, also you can use context menu on project **Maven->Update project configuration**.

Comment: Thanks. The problem now is eclipse can't see source code of jars in repository when debugging. And I can't add Maven Dependencies to Source tab in Debug configurations to resolve it this way.

Comment: @bnguyen82 Use context menu Maven->Download Sources.

Comment: Sources are all already downloaded in repository. I can view and link my project source to them, just not when debugging. If I attach source manually for each jar, it works for that one.